# Jquery .attr() doesn't change my output name

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically generate an input field by following a tutorial , somehow the tutorial are using old version of Jquery , now i trying to get it done by using the latest jquery

this is the tutorial i follow on [old tutorial](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/)

No problem in cloning but i cannot generate the input with different name 
eg.

```
<input name="name1" value="">
<input name="name2" value="">
<input name="name3" value="">
```

Here is my testing code 
[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BgJhE/)

Thanks in advance

SOLVED with

```
<input name="name[]" value="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution!

`<input name="name[]" ... />`

This will send the data as an array, and it won't matter how many times it gets cloned.

Comment: Alright this really an easiest way to solve my problem , but I really don't know whats wrong with my code , sorry I'm not a jquery expert

Comment: I solved my problem with your solution , because as a good pratice , should always handle the data dynamically , Anyway thanks for the share and knowledge =)

Answer (score 2):

You never actually change the id of the input, only the select box before the input.  When  you clone into `newElem` you have to change both at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `:first` selector from the `children()` when you are setting the `id` and the `name` of the `input`, it should work. Also, you have got the order of `.find('input')` wrong

Your code would look something like

```
newElem.children(':first').find("input").prop('id', 'name' + newNum).prop('name', 'name' + newNum)
```

Here's a link to your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgJhE/3/)